# How to syncronised the worker threads in a FIFO queue in c++

Tags: c++, queue, worker-thread, synchronization

I am designing a C++ application that processes real-time audio stream that uses a Queue.

I am having trouble to understand the technology to use between multi-threading queue and dispatch queue. How to synchronize the worker threads?

Here is the process:

1. The main thread listen to a microphone to get audio input.
2. The main thread posts in the queue each time an audio signal is available and come back to his listening job.

**3. A worker thread will pop items from the queue and process the data**

I have implemented this concept in Android, Android have the "HandlerThread" class that does exactly the same job with a Looper to keep the queue alive. But in C++, I am not sure how to do so. I have read from [asynchronous dispatch queue](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/02/08/implementing-an-asynchronous-dispatch-queue/). But in this article, the posting method and worker thread are asynchronous.

The order is important to me, the order in which I return the results to the main thread must be as the order are taken from the queue.
If for example we have in the queue: data1 (first), data2 (second), data3 (third) I have to return to the main thread the results in the exact same order. I am stuck on how to do it in C++. If data3 thread terminates before data1 thread, my sequence is broken. I have to respect the sequence. I am afraid my threads will need heavy management. I would like to avoid this.

Basically I would like to do [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread) concept in c++. video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TN-CGfzvBhc)

Does anyone can help me to understand how to implement this in c++ or have a better idea?

I hope it's clear enough.
Thanks for your help.
Remy

Comment: Take your pick: `std::list`, `std::queue`, or a reasonably-large `std::vector` with circular queue semantics. Couple that with `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`, and perhaps a few more variables. Mission accomplished. You will find more details in your favorite C++ textbook that explains how to use C++ threads. Unfortunately, there's very little that you can "avoid" in C++. C++ standard library provides basic containers and resources, and it is up to the application to correctly do all heavy lifting and do what it needs to do.

Comment: read the [consumer- producer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84109/a-multi-threaded-producer-consumer-with-c11) desigin pattern

Comment: Ok thanks i will see this design pattern. But i thought the Dispatch queue would solve all the heavy lifting thread.

Comment: I wonder if I can have many consumers threads. My application deals with real time low latency, so if consumers are waiting, it is a waste of time. The consumers are never asleep,they don't need to wake up.  Maybe it is way too complex to design!